# R data.table apply function to rows using columns as arguments

Tags: r, data.table, mapply

I have the following `data.table`

```
x = structure(list(f1 = 1:3, f2 = 3:5), .Names = c("f1", "f2"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to apply a function to each row of the `data.table`. The function `func.test` uses args `f1` and `f2` and does something with it and returns a computed value. Assume (as an example)

```
func.text <- function(arg1,arg2){ return(arg1 + exp(arg2))}
```

but my real function is more complex and does loops and all, but returns a computed value.
What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The best way is to write a vectorized function, but if you can't, then perhaps this will do:

```
x[, func.text(f1, f2), by = seq_len(nrow(x))]
```

Comment: Ah, didn't think of using <code>by = 1:nrow(x)</code> trick. Nice one

Comment: Not sure why not just use `.I`, e.g., something like `x[, func.text(f1, f2), by = .I]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I have no idea what `by=.I` is doing. It's somehow not quite the same as `by=1:nrow(x)`, as you can check by comparing e.g. `x[, 1, by = .I]` and `x[, 1, by = 1:nrow(x)]`.

Comment: would be great though if that worked as you'd expect it to work (also `by=1:.N`)

Comment: Yeah you probably right, but in this case it doesn't even look like the OP needs a `by` statement here, as his function already operates over the whole data set by row, so even `x[, func.text(f1, f2)]` will give the desired result. The problem will be that it will lose the `data.table` class and become a numeric vector. Adding `by = .I`  will keep the class, but I'm not sure why or how (I'll probably will get some angry comment from @Arun pointing out my lack of understanding in `data.table` soon)

Comment: Hmm.. Could you explain why writing vectorized function would be better than this? To me this looks very clean and easy. (cleaner and easier than vectorizing the function).

Comment: @Pekka having a vectorized function would result in a lot fewer function calls and would be faster

Comment: This breaks when `x` has zero rows.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn if you have zero rows, then you're solving a different problem from "applying function to rows"

Comment: @eddi I disagree. I have production code that needs to apply a function to the rows of some given `data.table`, but the # of rows of the `data.table` is not known in advance and could potentially be zero.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn that doesn't change that it's a different problem, but I'm too lazy to keep arguing this minor point - new edit will be fine

Answer (score 30):

The most elegant way I've found is with `mapply`:

```r
x[, value := mapply(func.text, f1, f2)]
x
#    f1 f2    value
# 1:  1  3 21.08554
# 2:  2  4 56.59815
# 3:  3  5 151.4132
```

Or with the `purrr` package:

```r
x[, value := purrr::pmap_dbl(.(f1, f2), func.text)]
```

---

If your situation allows for it, another approach would be to match the arguments names to the column names to use:

```r
library("purrr")

# arguments match the names of the columns, dots collect other 
# columns existing in the data.table
func.text <- function(f1, f2, ...) { return(f1 + exp(f2)) }

# use `set` to modify the data.table by reference
purrr::pmap_dbl(x, func.text) %>%
  data.table::set(x, i = NULL, j = "value", value = .)

print(x)
##    f1 f2     value
## 1:  1  3  21.08554
## 2:  2  4  56.59815
## 3:  3  5 151.41316
```

Answer (score 9):

We can define rows with `.I` function.

```
dt_iris <- data.table(iris)
dt_iris[, ..I := .I]

## Let's define some function
some_fun <- function(dtX) {
    print('hello')
    return(dtX[, Sepal.Length / Sepal.Width])
}

## by row
dt_iris[, some_fun(.SD), by = ..I] # or simply: dt_iris[, some_fun(.SD), by = .I]

## vectorized calculation
some_fun(dt_iris)
```

Comment: I am under the impression there was an age it was possible to directly use `by=.I` in the third component. No ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent sure, it is just to indicate that user sees the data, he applies `by` on. I have updated post to remove any doubt ;)

Comment: Sorry CronAcronis, maybe my comment is not clear. I mean it was possible to direclty do `dt[, y:=somefun(x), by=I]` in the past. But it is no possible now. Or maybe my memory is wrong.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I think you meant `.I`, so you can do `dt_iris[, some_fun(.SD), by = .I]`, with dot.

Comment: Yes sorry, I meant `.I`. But I tried it yesterday and it didn't work... Hmm I have just tried now and it works.. Sorry, I was surely too tired :)

Comment: What's the meaning of ..I ?

Comment: @skan just for convenience to have actual counter persisted, no special meaning.

Comment: Note that `.I` is meant to be used as a `j` argument in `data.table`, and not in the `by` clause. In DT >1.12.4 it doesn't seem to work either. @CronMerdek, can you re-evaluate your answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty compact syntax

```
x[, c := .(Map(func.text, f1, f2))]
```