# New column by applying function to another column in data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

Here is a sample data frame of the data I am working with. It is basically a modified VCF file for those who are familiar with genetic data formats. If not, essentially each row contains information for a position in the genome where a variant may exist.

```
samp <- structure(list(Chrom = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "chr12", class = "factor"), 
    Pos = c(8613204L, 8613412L, 8614238L, 8614506L, 8614652L, 
    8614669L, 8614768L, 8614951L, 8614986L, 8615225L, 8615809L, 
    8616149L, 8616392L), Ref = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "C", "G", 
    "T"), class = "factor"), Alt = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("A", "C", 
    "G", "T"), class = "factor"), Info = c("AC=3913;AF=0.78135;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=-128;EAS_AF=0.9921;AMR_AF=0.8357;AFR_AF=0.5779;EUR_AF=0.7366;SAS_AF=0.8466;AA=G|||;CSQ=G|ENSG00000205846|ENST00000382073|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000382073;FUNSEQ=0.1881", 
    "AC=4051;AF=0.808906;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=-128;EAS_AF=0.9921;AMR_AF=0.8444;AFR_AF=0.6725;EUR_AF=0.7366;SAS_AF=0.8538;AA=C|||;CSQ=C|ENSG00000205846|ENST00000382073|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000382073;FUNSEQ=0.1881", 
    "AC=4021;AF=0.802915;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=-128;EAS_AF=0.9921;AMR_AF=0.8415;AFR_AF=0.6558;EUR_AF=0.7376;SAS_AF=0.8466;AA=T|||;CSQ=C|ENSG00000205846|ENST00000382073|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000382073;FUNSEQ=0.7997", 
    "AC=3990;AF=0.796725;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=-128;EAS_AF=0.9921;AMR_AF=0.8386;AFR_AF=0.6339;EUR_AF=0.7376;SAS_AF=0.8466;AA=A|||;CSQ=A|ENSG00000205846|ENST00000382073|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000382073;FUNSEQ=0.1881", 
    "AC=4069;AF=0.8125;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=17188;EAS_AF=0.9921;AMR_AF=0.8487;AFR_AF=0.6528;EUR_AF=0.7714;SAS_AF=0.8599;AA=A|||;CSQ=A|ENSG00000205846|ENST00000382073|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000382073;FUNSEQ=0.0029", 
    "AC=4044;AF=0.807508;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=-128;EAS_AF=0.9911;AMR_AF=0.8458;AFR_AF=0.6362;EUR_AF=0.7714;SAS_AF=0.8599;AA=G|||;CSQ=A|ENSG00000205846|ENST00000382073|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000382073;FUNSEQ=0.0029", 
    NA, NA, "AC=3795;AF=0.757788;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=-128;EAS_AF=0.9653;AMR_AF=0.7954;AFR_AF=0.5651;EUR_AF=0.7167;SAS_AF=0.82;AA=c|||;CSQ=A|ENSG00000205846|ENST00000382073|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000382073;FUNSEQ=0.0029", 
    NA, "AC=4053;AF=0.809305;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=-128;EAS_AF=0.9921;AMR_AF=0.8458;AFR_AF=0.6362;EUR_AF=0.7724;SAS_AF=0.8671;AA=C|||;CSQ=T|ENSG00000205846|ENST00000382073|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000382073;FUNSEQ=0.0029", 
    "AC=4076;AF=0.813898;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=-128;EAS_AF=0.9921;AMR_AF=0.8473;AFR_AF=0.6528;EUR_AF=0.7724;SAS_AF=0.8671;AA=C|||;CSQ=C|ENSG00000205846|ENST00000382073|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000382073;FUNSEQ=0.0029", 
    "AC=4052;AF=0.809105;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=-128;EAS_AF=0.9921;AMR_AF=0.8473;AFR_AF=0.6346;EUR_AF=0.7724;SAS_AF=0.8671;AA=T|||;CSQ=T|ENSG00000205846|ENST00000382073|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000382073;FUNSEQ=0.0029"
    ), TG_rs = c("rs10770739", "rs10770740", "rs4883148", "rs4883149", 
    "rs4883150", "rs4883151", NA, NA, "rs7303948", NA, "rs4242889", 
    "rs4883154", "rs4242890")), row.names = c(NA, -13L), .Names = c("Chrom", 
"Pos", "Ref", "Alt", "Info", "TG_rs"), class = "data.frame")
```

What I would like to do is extract values from the "Info" column. However, the information contained in this column is not the same for each row, and does not always occur in the same order. Thus, I want to use pattern matching to get values of interest to me.

I wrote a little function to extract the "allele frequencies" (AF) for various "super populations" (eg. AMR, AFR, EUR, SAS, EAS) which are contained in the Info column.

```
extractAF <- function(pop, vec) {
  info <- unlist((strsplit(vec, ";", fixed=TRUE)))
  AF <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit((info[grep(pop, (unlist((strsplit(vec, ";", fixed=TRUE)))))]), "=", fixed=TRUE))[2])
  return(AF)
}
```

This function requires two arguments: the 'pop' which is a string specifying which super population to extract, and the 'vec' which is designed to take the Info column of my dataframe.

The function works as expected when passing a single vector through:

```
extractAF("AFR_AF", samp[1,'Info'])
#[1] 0.5779

extractAF("AFR_AF", samp[5,'Info'])
#[1] 0.6528
```

However, I wish to do it to each row of the dataframe and create a new column containing the data. When I use the mutate function of dplyr, I wind up with a column of the same value:

```
library("dplyr")
mutate(samp, AFR_AF = extractAF("AFR_AF", Info))
```

I read a post (that I can't seem to find now otherwise I would reference it) that said mutate is passing all the rows at once, instead of row-by-row which I need.

So I tried a few other ways below based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431307/r-data-table-apply-function-to-rows-using-columns-as-arguments) :

```
apply(samp[,'Info'], 1, function(x) extractAF("AFR_AF", x))
```

Error in apply(samp[, "Info"], 1, function(x) extractAF("AMR_AF", x)) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

```
samp[, extractAF("AMR_AF", Info), by = .I]
```

Error in `[.data.frame`(samp, , extractAF("AMR_AF", Info), by = .I) : 
  unused argument (by = .I)

```
samp[, extractAF("AMR_AF", Info), by = 1:nrow(samp)]

Error in `[.data.frame`(samp, , extractAF("AMR_AF", Info), by = 1:nrow(samp)) : 
  unused argument (by = 1:nrow(samp))
```

#

UPDATE

Additional sample dataset that contains an NA and AF=0 in the INFO column below:

> structure(list(CHROM = c("chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", 
>   "chr1"), POS = c(16090898L, 16091074L, 16091583L, 16092212L, 
>   16093560L, 16093639L), ID = c("rs6429774", "rs6429776", NA,
>   "rs74528955",  "rs904912", NA), REF = c("G", "A", "T", "C", "T", "C"),
>   ALT = c("A",  "G", "A", "T", "A", "T"), QUAL = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
>   NA), FILTER = c(NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), INFO =
>   c("AC=1606;AF=0.320687;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=21565;EAS_AF=0.1419;AMR_AF=0.2983;AFR_AF=0.525;EUR_AF=0.3509;SAS_AF=0.2137;AA=G|||;CSQ=A|ENSG00000162458|ENST00000441801|Transcript|upstream_gene_variant|||||||96|1||||||;ERB=A||proximal_1216|Regulatory_Feature|proximal_enhancer;FUNSEQ=0.3335",  "AC=1690;AF=0.33746;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=20247;EAS_AF=0.1498;AMR_AF=0.3012;AFR_AF=0.5681;EUR_AF=0.3549;SAS_AF=0.227;AA=G|||;CSQ=G|ENSG00000162458|ENST00000441801|Transcript|5_prime_UTR_variant|81|||||||1||||||;ERB=G||proximal_1216|Regulatory_Feature|proximal_enhancer;FUNSEQ=0.3335",  NA,
>   "AC=8;AF=0.00159744;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=19197;EAS_AF=0.0079;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0;AA=C|||;CSQ=T|ENSG00000162458|ENST00000441801|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000441801;ERB=T||proximal_1216|Regulatory_Feature|proximal_enhancer;FUNSEQ=0.3335",  "AC=3282;AF=0.655351;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=14721;EAS_AF=0.8343;AMR_AF=0.6916;AFR_AF=0.4259;EUR_AF=0.6531;SAS_AF=0.7577;AA=A|||;CSQ=A|ENSG00000162458|ENST00000441801|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000441801;FUNSEQ=0.1483",
>   "AC=5;AF=0.000998403;AN=5008;NS=2504;DP=14736;EAS_AF=0.003;AMR_AF=0;AFR_AF=0;EUR_AF=0;SAS_AF=0.002;AA=C|||;CSQ=T|ENSG00000162458|ENST00000441801|Transcript|intron_variant||||||||1||||||;GENCODE=ENST00000441801;FUNSEQ=0.1483"
>   )), row.names = 14:19, class = "data.frame", .Names = c("CHROM", 
>   "POS", "ID", "REF", "ALT", "QUAL", "FILTER", "INFO"))

Comment: Your apply function was close `apply(samp, 1, function(x) extractAF("AFR_AF", x[5]))`

Comment: Please format your code properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not need those formulas since `sub` is vectorized. First create a variable of all possible codes like (AFR, AMR, EUR, etc...). Use that vector to create a search pattern to go through the `Info` column and return a new data frame with all matches:

```
all_pop <- c("AMR_AF", "AFR_AF", "EUR_AF", "SAS_AF", "EAS_AF")
pat <- paste0(".*\\b", all_pop, "=(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\b.*")

out <- sapply(pat, sub, "\\1", samp$Info)
newdf <- setNames(as.data.frame(out), all_pop)
#      AMR_AF AFR_AF EUR_AF SAS_AF EAS_AF
#   1  0.8357 0.5779 0.7366 0.8466 0.9921
#   2  0.8444 0.6725 0.7366 0.8538 0.9921
#   3  0.8415 0.6558 0.7376 0.8466 0.9921
#   4  0.8386 0.6339 0.7376 0.8466 0.9921
#   5  0.8487 0.6528 0.7714 0.8599 0.9921
#   6  0.8458 0.6362 0.7714 0.8599 0.9911
#   7    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#   8    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#   9  0.7954 0.5651 0.7167   0.82 0.9653
#   10   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
#   11 0.8458 0.6362 0.7724 0.8671 0.9921
#   12 0.8473 0.6528 0.7724 0.8671 0.9921
#   13 0.8473 0.6346 0.7724 0.8671 0.9921
```

Comment: Very nice solution! Any reason not to use "cbind" to combine this with the original dataframe?

Comment: Yes you can combine it however you find best

Comment: In applying this to my larger dataset, I run into a problem when the AF = 0. My knowledge of regexp is very poor, but I am assuming this has something to do with the "d+"?

Comment: I'm playing around with an 'or': ".*\\bAMR_AF=(\\d+\\.?\\d+)\\b.*|.*\\bAMR_AF=(\\d)\\b.*", but this just returns a blank rather than a '0'

Comment: I updated the regex pattern. Check the edited answer. The difference is `pat` now has `(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)` to say "one digit" or "one digit followed by a period and other digits".

Comment: Thank you Pierre! Code works with desired behavior now!