# Applying custom function to data.table by row returns incorrect amount of values

Tags: r, data.table, genomicranges

I'm kind of new to data.tables and I have a table containing DNA genomic coordinates like this:

```
       chrom   pause strand coverage
    1:     1 3025794      +        1
    2:     1 3102057      +        2
    3:     1 3102058      +        2
    4:     1 3102078      +        1
    5:     1 3108840      -        1
    6:     1 3133041      +        1
```

I wrote a custom function that I want to apply to each row of my circa 2 million rows table, it uses GenomicFeatures' mapToTranscripts to retrieve two related values in form of a string and a new coordinate. I want to add them to my table in two new columns, like this:

```
       chrom   pause strand coverage       transcriptID CDS
    1:     1 3025794      +        1 ENSMUST00000116652 196
    2:     1 3102057      +        2 ENSMUST00000116652  35
    3:     1 3102058      +        2 ENSMUST00000156816 888
    4:     1 3102078      +        1 ENSMUST00000156816 883
    5:     1 3108840      -        1 ENSMUST00000156816 882
    6:     1 3133041      +        1 ENSMUST00000156816 880
```

The function is the following:

```
    get_feature <- function(dt){

      coordinate <- GRanges(dt$chrom, IRanges(dt$pause, width = 1), dt$strand) 
      hit <- mapToTranscripts(coordinate, cds_canonical, ignore.strand = FALSE) 
      tx_id <- tx_names[as.character(seqnames(hit))] 
      cds_coordinate <- sapply(ranges(hit), '[[', 1)

      if(length(tx_id) == 0 || length(cds_coordinate) == 0) {  
        out <- list('NaN', 0)
      } else {
        out <- list(tx_id, cds_coordinate)
      }

      return(out)
    }
```

Then, I do:

```
    counts[, c("transcriptID", "CDS"):=get_feature(.SD), by = .I]
```

And I get this error, indicating that the function is returning two lists of shorter length than the original table, instead of one new element per row:

```
Warning messages:
    1: In `[.data.table`(counts, , `:=`(c("transcriptID", "CDS"),  ... :
      Supplied 1112452 items to be assigned to 1886614 items of column 'transcriptID' (recycled leaving remainder of 774162 items).
    2: In `[.data.table`(counts, , `:=`(c("transcriptID", "CDS"),  ... :
      Supplied 1112452 items to be assigned to 1886614 items of column 'CDS' (recycled leaving remainder of 774162 items).
```

I assumed that using the **.I**  operator would apply the function on a row basis and return one value per row. I also made sure the function was not returning empty values using the **if** statement.

Then I tried this mock version of the function:

```
    get_feature <- function(dt) {

      return('I should be returned once for each row')

    }
```

And called it like this:

```
    new.table <- counts[, get_feature(.SD), by = .I]
```

It makes a 1 row data table, instead of one the original length. So I concluded that my function, or maybe the way I'm calling it, is collapsing the elements of the resulting vector somehow. What am I doing wrong?

**Update (with solution):** As @StatLearner pointed out, it is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667335/row-operations-in-data-table-using-by-i?answertab=votes#tab-top) that, as explained in `?data.table`, `.I` is only intended for use in `j` (as in `DT[i,j,by=]`). Therefore, `by=.I` is equivalent to `by=NULL` and the proper syntax is `by=1:nrow(dt)` in order to group by row number and apply the function row-wise.

Unfortunately, for my particular case, this is utterly inefficient and I calculated an execution time of 20 seconds for 100 rows. For my 36 million row dataset that takes 3 months to complete.

In my case, I had to give up and use the `mapToTranscripts` function on the entire table like this, which takes a couple of seconds and was obviously the intended use.

```
    get_features <- function(dt){
      coordinate <- GRanges(dt$chrom, IRanges(dt$pause, width = 1), dt$strand) # define coordinate
      hits <- mapToTranscripts(coordinate, cds_canonical, ignore.strand = FALSE) # map it to a transcript
      tx_hit <- as.character(seqnames(hits)) # get transcript number
      tx_id <- tx_names[tx_hit] # get transcript name from translation table

      return(data.table('transcriptID'= tx_id, 
                       'CDS_coordinate' =  start(hits))
    }

     density <- counts[, get_features(.SD)]
```

Then map back to the genome using `mapFromTranscripts` from `GenomicFeatures` package so I could use a `data.tables` join to retrieve information from the original table, which was the intended purpose of what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I do it when I need to apply a function for each row in a data.table is grouping it by row number:

```
counts[, get_feature(.SD), by = 1:nrow(counts)]
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37667335/row-operations-in-data-table-using-by-i?answertab=votes#tab-top),`.I` is not intended for using in `by` since it should return the sequence of row indices that is produced by grouping. The reason why `by = .I` doesn't throw an error is that data.table creates object `.I` equals `NULL` in data.table namespace, hence `by = .I` is equivalent to `by = NULL`.

Note that using `by=1:nrow(dt)` groups by row number and allows your function to access only a  single row from data.table:

```
require(data.table)
counts <- data.table(chrom = sample.int(10, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                     pause = sample((3 * 10^6):(3.2 * 10^6), size = 100), 
                     strand = sample(c('-','+'), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                     coverage = sample.int(3, size = 100, replace = TRUE))

get_feature <- function(dt){
    coordinate <- data.frame(dt$chrom, dt$pause, dt$strand)
    rowNum <- nrow(coordinate)
    return(list(text = 'Number of rows in dt', rowNum = rowNum))  
}

counts[, get_feature(.SD), by = 1:nrow(counts)]
```

will produce a data.table with the same number of rows as in `counts`, but `coordinate` will contain just a single row from `counts`

```
   nrow                 text rowNum
1:    1 Number of rows in dt      1
2:    2 Number of rows in dt      1
3:    3 Number of rows in dt      1
4:    4 Number of rows in dt      1
5:    5 Number of rows in dt      1
```

while `by = NULL` will supply the entire data.table to the function:

```
counts[, get_feature(.SD), by = NULL]

                   text rowNum
1: Number of rows in dt    100
```

which is the intended way for `by` to work.

Comment: Nice answer @StatLearner. Welcome to SO!

Comment: That is indeed true, @StatLearner, I checked with `by=NULL` and the result is the same. Using `by=1:NROW(dt)` applies the function the way I wanted, but it's incredibly slow, so I had to look for another workaround. I can not use this function the way I wanted to but I learned a great deal about `data.tables` today so, thank you very much!

Comment: PS: The funny thing is that I got the `by=.I` idea from [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431307/r-data-table-apply-function-to-rows-using-columns-as-arguments) which is the first one that appears by a Google search of _"apply function to each row datatable"_. I will link the answer you mention there just in case someone gets the same idea as me.

Comment: You are wellcome, @AntonioMartínez! I agree about `by = .I`, it's counter-intuitive and it was also the first thing I tried.