# apply a vector-valued to a datatable

Tags: r, data.table

I'm feeling a bit shameful to ask this question but I have not used `datatables` for a couple of months and I've forgotten a lost of things. I've spent two hours to search for the documentation but unsuccessfully. However this is a trivial question.

I have this datatable:

```
DT = data.table(CJ(r=c(0,1,2),phi=c(1,2,3),theta=c(10,11,12)))
DT
> DT
    r phi theta
 1: 0   1    10
 2: 0   1    11
 3: 0   1    12
 4: 0   2    10
 5: 0   2    11
 6: 0   2    12
 7: 0   3    10
 8: 0   3    11
 9: 0   3    12
10: 1   1    10
11: 1   1    11
12: 1   1    12
13: 1   2    10
14: 1   2    11
15: 1   2    12
16: 1   3    10
17: 1   3    11
18: 1   3    12
19: 2   1    10
20: 2   1    11
21: 2   1    12
22: 2   2    10
23: 2   2    11
24: 2   2    12
25: 2   3    10
26: 2   3    11
27: 2   3    12
    r phi theta
```

As you see, it has 27 rows. Now I want to apply a vector-valued to each row. Naively:

```
f <- function(r, phi, theta) (2*r, 2*phi 3*theta)
```

and then

```
> DT[,f(r, phi, theta), by="r,phi,theta"]
    r phi theta       V1
 1: 0   1    10  0.00000
 2: 0   1    10  0.00000
 3: 0   1    10  0.00000
 4: 0   1    11  0.00000
 5: 0   1    11  0.00000
 6: 0   1    11  0.00000
 7: 0   1    12  0.00000
 8: 0   1    12  0.00000
 9: 0   1    12  0.00000
10: 0   2    10  0.00000
11: 0   2    10  0.00000
12: 0   2    10  0.00000
13: 0   2    11  0.00000
14: 0   2    11  0.00000
15: 0   2    11  0.00000
16: 0   2    12  0.00000
17: 0   2    12  0.00000
18: 0   2    12  0.00000
19: 0   3    10  0.00000
20: 0   3    10  0.00000
21: 0   3    10  0.00000
22: 0   3    11  0.00000
23: 0   3    11  0.00000
24: 0   3    11  0.00000
25: 0   3    12  0.00000
26: 0   3    12  0.00000
27: 0   3    12  0.00000
28: 1   1    10 -0.29394
29: 1   1    10 -0.45778
30: 1   1    10 -0.83907
31: 1   1    11 -0.54030
32: 1   1    11 -0.84146
33: 1   1    11  0.00443
34: 1   1    12 -0.28991
35: 1   1    12 -0.45151
36: 1   1    12  0.84385
37: 1   2    10  0.22639
38: 1   2    10 -0.49468
39: 1   2    10 -0.83907
40: 1   2    11  0.41614
41: 1   2    11 -0.90929
42: 1   2    11  0.00443
43: 1   2    12  0.22329
44: 1   2    12 -0.48790
45: 1   2    12  0.84385
46: 1   3    10  0.53858
47: 1   3    10 -0.07677
48: 1   3    10 -0.83907
49: 1   3    11  0.98998
50: 1   3    11 -0.14112
51: 1   3    11  0.00443
52: 1   3    12  0.53120
53: 1   3    12 -0.07572
54: 1   3    12  0.84385
55: 2   1    10 -0.58787
56: 2   1    10 -0.91556
57: 2   1    10 -1.67814
58: 2   1    11 -1.08059
59: 2   1    11 -1.68293
60: 2   1    11  0.00885
61: 2   1    12 -0.57982
62: 2   1    12 -0.90302
63: 2   1    12  1.68771
64: 2   2    10  0.45279
65: 2   2    10 -0.98935
66: 2   2    10 -1.67814
67: 2   2    11  0.83229
68: 2   2    11 -1.81858
69: 2   2    11  0.00885
70: 2   2    12  0.44659
71: 2   2    12 -0.97581
72: 2   2    12  1.68771
73: 2   3    10  1.07715
74: 2   3    10 -0.15354
75: 2   3    10 -1.67814
76: 2   3    11  1.97997
77: 2   3    11 -0.28224
78: 2   3    11  0.00885
79: 2   3    12  1.06241
80: 2   3    12 -0.15144
81: 2   3    12  1.68771
    r phi theta       V1
```

The resulat has 81 columns. This is not what I want. I want 27 columns, each with 3 values. How to do that please ?

Comment: `DT[, f(r, phi, theta), by=rowid(r)]` ...see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431307/r-data-table-apply-function-to-rows-using-columns-as-arguments

Comment: @chinsoon12 Thanks but that does not work. Still 81 rows. I'll take a look at the link you posted.

Comment: @chinsoon12 I'm afraid my question was not clear enough. The link you posted does not answer the question. Or maybe that's me who misunderstand....

Comment: 27 rows or 27 columns? you can try this `f <- function(r, phi, theta) list(2*r, 2*phi, 3*theta); DT[, f(r, phi, theta)]` ...maybe you can post your desired output as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let f return a list:

```
f <- function(r, phi, theta) list(2*r, 2*phi, 3*theta)
```

Next, If you want to name your new columns f1,f2 and f3:

```
DT[,c('f1','f2','f3'):=f(r,phi,theta)]

 DT
    r phi theta f1 f2 f3
 1: 0   1    10  0  2 30
 2: 0   1    11  0  2 33
 3: 0   1    12  0  2 36
 4: 0   2    10  0  4 30
 5: 0   2    11  0  4 33
 6: 0   2    12  0  4 36
 7: 0   3    10  0  6 30
 8: 0   3    11  0  6 33
 9: 0   3    12  0  6 36
10: 1   1    10  2  2 30
11: 1   1    11  2  2 33
12: 1   1    12  2  2 36
13: 1   2    10  2  4 30
14: 1   2    11  2  4 33
15: 1   2    12  2  4 36
16: 1   3    10  2  6 30
17: 1   3    11  2  6 33
18: 1   3    12  2  6 36
19: 2   1    10  4  2 30
20: 2   1    11  4  2 33
21: 2   1    12  4  2 36
22: 2   2    10  4  4 30
23: 2   2    11  4  4 33
24: 2   2    12  4  4 36
25: 2   3    10  4  6 30
26: 2   3    11  4  6 33
27: 2   3    12  4  6 36
    r phi theta f1 f2 f3
```