# Is there a way to self reference a data.table in i

Tags: r, data.table, self-reference

Consider the standard data.table syntax `DT[i, j, ...]`. Since `.SD` is only defined in `j` and `NULL` in `i`, is there any way to implicitly (desired) or explicitly (via something like `.SD`) refer to the current data.table in a function in `i`?

#### Use Case

I would like to write a function that filters standard columns. The column names are the same across multiple tables and somewhat verbose. To speed up my coding by less typing, I would like to write a function like this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(postal_code   = c("USA123", "SPEEDO", "USA421"),
                 customer_name = c("Taylor", "Walker", "Thompson"))
dt
#>    postal_code customer_name
#> 1:      USA123        Taylor
#> 2:      SPEEDO        Walker
#> 3:      USA421      Thompson

# Filter all customers from a common postal code 
# that surname starts with specific letters
extract <- function(x, y, DT) {
  DT[, startsWith(postal_code, x) & startsWith(customer_name, y)]
}


# does not work
dt[extract("USA", "T", .SD)]
#> Error in .checkTypos(e, names_x): Object 'postal_code' not found.
#>    Perhaps you intended postal_code

# works but requires specifying the data.table explicitly
# plus the drawback that it cannot be called upon, e.g. a grouped .SD
# in a nested call
dt[extract("USA", "T", dt)]
#>    postal_code customer_name
#> 1:      USA123        Taylor
#> 2:      USA421      Thompson
```

##### Desired (pseudo code)

```
dt[extract("USA", "T")]
#>    postal_code customer_name
#> 1:      USA123        Taylor
#> 2:      USA421      Thompson

# but also
# subsequent steps in j
dt[extract("USA", "T"), relevant := TRUE][]
#>    postal_code customer_name relevant
#> 1:      USA123        Taylor     TRUE
#> 2:      SPEEDO        Walker       NA
#> 3:      USA421      Thompson     TRUE

# using other data.tables
another_dt[extract("USA", "T")]
yet_another_dt[extract("USA", "T")]
```

Comment: Seems like `fcase` can handle your second use-case: `dt[, relevant := fcase(extract("USA", "T", dt), TRUE, default = NA)][]`. Do you have other uses in mind that `fcase` wouldn't handle?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know that there are multiple ways to yield the desired result in `j`. However, I really would like to trigger everything in `i` since it is much more versatile and convenient. Often I first inspect the filtered rows and update them subsequently. Furthermore `dt[extract("USA", "T"), relevant := TRUE]` would be much clearer to read than `dt[, relevant := fcase(extract("USA", "T", dt), TRUE, default = NA)]`. It is not about "How can I get this result" but very specific to "How can I use such a function in `i`.

Comment: It's admittedly not as readable, but wouldn't the approach in this answer give the desired versatility?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57091155/9463489

Comment: Just for the record, I think this may a related (open) issue: [New symbol .D to refer to x in i](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4685)

Comment: @jblood94 Not exactly since again I would have to type `dt` which I try to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a `data.table` expert but you can try the following workaround

```
> dt[,.SD[extract("USA", "T", .SD)]]
   postal_code customer_name
1:      USA123        Taylor
2:      USA421      Thompson
```

where you play self-reference at `j` within `.SD`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, just filtering is not the only use case. I would also like to use it for all sorts of `i` actions, e.g. updating. Sorry for being not precise enough. I updated my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible approach...

```
#create named vector
mystr <- c(postal_code = "USA", customer_name = "T")
#build query text
query <- paste0("grepl(\"^", mystr, "\", ", names(mystr), ")", collapse = " & ")
#eval/parse dynamic text
dt[eval(parse(text = query)), ]
#    postal_code customer_name
# 1:      USA123        Taylor
# 2:      USA421      Thompson
```

Comment: Nice idea to use `eval(parse(...))`. However, is there any possibility to "hide" it inside of `extract()`? Using eval - parse in top-level code is undesirable.